# swift 3 A very weird issue with the function parameter when calling post() of AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift

I'm newbie with ios programming. And now I can not explain for the weird situation as following:

```
let url: String = isFavorite ? "1.1/favorites/create.json" : "1.1/favorites/destroy.json"  
post(url, parameters: params, progress: nil, success: { (task, response) -> Void in
            let dictionary = response as! NSDictionary
            let tweet = Tweet(dictionary: dictionary)
            success(tweet)
        }, failure: { (task, error) -> Void in
            print("like tweet error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            failure?(error)
        })
```

It always throws the exception:

```
like tweet error: Request failed: not found (404)
```

It's OK when I try as below (pass the url value directly instead of a variable):

```
post("1.1/favorites/create.json", parameters: params, ...
```

Because the error is 404, so maybe the url is not recognized by post() method, I really don't know what is the difference between them?

Comment: Also is it work when you pass: post("1.1/favorites/destroy.json", parameters: parms,..)?

Comment: @DiegoQ: yes, it always works with constant value

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the url string in allowed url

```
var url: String = isFavorite ? "1.1/favorites/create.json" : "1.1/favorites/destroy.json"
url = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
post(url, parameters: params, progress: nil, success: { (task, response) -> Void in
        let dictionary = response as! NSDictionary
        let tweet = Tweet(dictionary: dictionary)
        success(tweet)
    }, failure: { (task, error) -> Void in
        print("like tweet error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        failure?(error)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @DiegoQ but nothing difference happens :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this.:)

```
let url: URLStringConvertible = isFavorite ? "1.1/favorites/create.json" : "1.1/favorites/destroy.json"
```

Comment: URLStringConvertible comes from Alamofire, right? However, when I install Alamofire (with the default version), a lot of compiler errors appear in Alamofire source code T.T, for i.e: ```Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:94:24: '.dynamicType' is deprecated. Use 'type(of: ...)' instead```

Comment: When I try with Alamofire version 4, it can compile, however the url parameter of post() method is a String, so it can not apply for a URLConvertible object (URLStringConvertible went away in Alamofire version 4)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a breakpoint in the callback method, to see what happens

Comment: If you mean, it goes to the failure callback with error 404.